# ¿Como puedo Colocar una condicion en un CSS?

Tags: html, css

Necesito hacer una condicion en un css que si la patantalla llega a 1200 px o mas acomode unos estilos que ya tengo

Comment: porque no lo realizas con javascript?

Comment: @JuanL No es necesario usar `JavaScript` con `Media Querys` se puede solucionar?

Comment: Asi es, con media query tambien se puede utilizar. queda en tu criterio combinar ambos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede realizar con un media query.

```css
div {
    background: deepskyblue;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    div {
        background: #ef4c4c;
     }
}
```

```html
<div>Hola mundo</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberías agregar el código que tienes para que sea mas fácil ayudarte con un problema específico. Sin embargo, lo que requieres se logra con Media Querys:

```css
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    }
```